# How to mark as selected rows in an angular material table when object exists in another array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to mark the rows of the table as selected if they are in a different array then the tables dataSource.

This is what I've done so far:

component.ts

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MyModel>([]);
selection = new SelectionModel<MyModel>(true, []);
arrayToCompareWith: AnotherModel[];

//The part use for selection in UI copy from Angular Material Docs
isAllSelected() {
  const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
  const numRows = this.resultsDs.data.length;
  return numSelected === numRows;
}

masterToggle() {
  this.isAllSelected() ?
  this.selection.clear() :
  this.resultsDs.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
}

checkboxLabel(row?: SdsSectionModel): string {
  if (!row) {
    return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
  }
  return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.sectionId + 1}`;
}

\\The method I'm trying to use to select the rows in code
addToSelectedRows(): void{
  for(let option of this.arrayToCompareWith){
     \\myModelProp is of type MyModel
     this.selection.toggle(option.myModelProp);
  }
}
```

This actually selects the objects and adds them to selection object but it does not update the UI.

and this is the html for the selection column it was taken from the angular material docs also:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
   </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <div style="width: 3px">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                      [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some little bit more research I change the addToSelected method to this:

```
private addToSelected(): void {
  for (let option of this.arrayToCompareWith) {
     const exists = this.dataSource.data.filter(x => x.id === option.myModelProp.id)[0];
     this.selection.toggle(exists);
  }
}
```

Turns out I was passing the wrong object of the wrong array.

Comment: Thank you so much! With some changes this also worked for me. But I'm still wondered - for 2023 there is still no way to put selected rows for checkbox or selected row for radio button???